# Linq select from database table where matching property from List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List with records of following class which is something like this

```
  public class TestRecord
  {
     public int RecordsId{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
-- and more such properties.

  }
```

Now I have database table which I access from linq which contains RecordId column , values which will match RecordId value from above List.

```
  var result=from p in _context.Details
```

however I am thinking I could do where/ contains on this linq query and provide it with a clause to match RecordId from a list

```
 List<TestRecord> records -- this has let's say 100 records.
```

Doing simply this does not work as linq can't join with generic List

```
    var finalresult = from p in context.details
                      join a in records on p.recordId equals a.recordId
```

Any solutions for this using Linq?

Comment: `_context.Details` is a `DataTable`?

Comment: It's table in database

Comment: You can use a where clause in LINQ. Also to take only 100 records, you can use 'take' 'skip' ... If I have understood your question correctly. Provide some more info on what will go in your where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got a solution in vb.net. I guess it will no problem for you to translate.

My Class TestRecord:

```
Public Class TestRecord
Private _RecordsID As Integer
Private _Name As String
Public Property RecordsID As Integer
    Get
        Return _RecordsID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _RecordsID = value
    End Set

End Property
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set

End Property
```

End Class

Then, your main Sub (or anything else)

```
   Dim records As New List(Of TestRecord)
    Dim context As New DataTable()
    context.Columns.Add("DataTableRecordID")
    context.Columns.Add("Name")
    For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        records.Add(New TestRecord With {
            .RecordsID = i,
            .Name = "TestUser" & i.ToString()})


        context.Rows.Add(i, "TestUser" & i.ToString())
    Next


    Dim FinalResult = From p In context.AsEnumerable()
                      Join a In records.AsEnumerable() On p.Field(Of String)("DataTableRecordID") Equals a.RecordsID
```

I got a little loop at the beginning to create some datarows and a datatable. I guess you use datatable (or Dataset) in your "context" => context.details example.

In the linq query, you can you set your field in the datatable and the generic list (TestRecord) will give you the needed column (a.RecordID) from itself.

Sry for my bad english x)

Comment: thnx! using AsEnumerable worked to join with Generic List.

Comment: Hi Mandar, nice to hear that. Please care of the field defintion. I did a mistake. In the Join statement (on p.field(OF String please use integer right here, because you definied the ID as integer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains()` like

```
var finalresult = context.details.Where(d => records.Contains(d.recordId));
```

Comment: records is not only a list of int/string. it also has other properties which is why this solution doesnt work. i need to filter on RecordId property of entities in records object.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar, what is `_context.Details` then? provide definition for that

Comment: In that case create a list of Id's to filter against, recordIds = records.select(r=>r.recordId).tolist(), and run the contains query against this

Comment: @Rahul table from database , queried by linq to entity

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any` like this:

```
var finalresult = context.details.Where(d => records.Any(r=>r.recordId == d.recordId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var s = from p in tests where names.Contains(p.Name) select p;
```